# Predict object position

Tags: c#, math, unity-game-engine

The intention of this code segment is to predict the location of an object based on it's forward velocity and angular velocity. However, the position is not show where it's supposed to be; first when going straight the predicted position is shown as the same as current position, and second when turning right the position is almost correct, but with a larger turning radius than expected (as shown in the image).

```
syncEndPosition = m_Rigidbody.position;
syncEndRotation = m_Rigidbody.rotation;
AngularVel = m_Rigidbody.angularVelocity.y; // radians per second
Vel = transform.InverseTransformDirection(m_Rigidbody.velocity).z;
averagePing = 0.5f;

Quaternion currentQuat = Quaternion.AngleAxis(syncEndRotation.eulerAngles.y, Vector3.up);
Vector3 currentDir = currentQuat * Vector3.forward;

float predictedYrot = syncEndRotation.eulerAngles.y + ((AngularVel) * (averagePing * 10));
Quaternion predictedQuat = Quaternion.AngleAxis(predictedYrot, Vector3.up);
Vector3 predictedDir = predictedQuat * Vector3.forward;

float radius = Vel / AngularVel;
float angle = AngleDiff(syncEndRotation.eulerAngles.y, predictedQuat.eulerAngles.y);
float predictedDist = (radius * Mathf.Sin(angle / 2f));

Vector3 predictedPos = syncEndPosition + (predictedDir * predictedDist);

Debug.DrawRay(syncEndPosition + Vector3.up, Vector3.down, Color.green); // current position
Debug.DrawRay(syncEndPosition + Vector3.up, currentDir, Color.gray); // current direction
Debug.DrawRay(syncEndPosition + Vector3.up, predictedDir * predictedDist, Color.yellow); // predicted direction
```

[image: predict position test]